# Vuejs client can't communicate with Go backend via gRPC on MacOS

Tags: docker, vue.js, go, grpc, envoyproxy

I built a simple web app with a VueJS front (client) and a Go back (server), using gRPC and protobuf.
In order to communicate, an envoy proxy has to be set up between them to convert web client HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2.
I have no issue deploying this app on Linux, and have dockerized all three services.

However, I cannot manage to get my services to communicate on MacOS.

The app repository is available here: https://github.com/42Projects/nPuzzle

The deploy folder contains the docker-compose file, the envoy.yaml file required for the envoy container, as well as all three dockerfiles.
On MacOS the last line of the envoy.yaml needs to be updated, `localhost` has to be changed to `host.docker.internal`.

The client contains a ping function (in client/src/App.vue), the window.location.hostname might need to be changed to the docker-machine IP, unsure about that, my tries made no difference:

```
    created () {
        this.client = new NpuzzleClient('http://' + window.location.hostname + ':8080', null, null);
        const ping = () => {
            let message = new Message();
            message.setMessage('ping');
            this.client.greets(message, {}, err => this.serverOnline = !err);
        };
        ping();
        window.setInterval(ping, 1000);
    },
```

which is executed every second, and will display that the server is online on the top right corner. I have been so far unsuccessful in reaching my server while deploying on MacOS. It works perfectly fine on Linux.

Here is the code for the go server, I think it is correct to listen on localhost:9090 as the server will be dockerized, but I might be wrong and the address might need to be changed.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    pb "github.com/42Projects/nPuzzle/proto"
    npuzzle "github.com/42Projects/nPuzzle/src"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "log"
    "net"
    "time"
)

var port = flag.Int("port", 9090, "the server port")

type server struct{}

func (s *server) Greets(ctx context.Context, message *pb.Message) (*pb.Message, error) {

    return &pb.Message{Message: "pong!"}, nil
}

func (s *server) Parse(ctx context.Context, message *pb.Message) (*pb.Matrix, error) {

    log.Printf("received parsing request: %#v", message.Message)
    m, err := npuzzle.ParseMatrix(message.Message)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return &pb.Matrix{
            Success: false,
            Error:   err.Error(),
        }, nil
    }

    rows := make([]*pb.Matrix_Row, len(m))
    for index, row := range m {

        /* We need unsigned 32bits integer for protobuf */
        uIntRow := make([]uint32, len(m))
        for rowIndex, num := range row {
            uIntRow[rowIndex] = uint32(num)
        }

        rows[index] = &pb.Matrix_Row{Num: uIntRow}
    }

    return &pb.Matrix{
        Success: true,
        Rows:    rows,
    }, nil
}

func (s *server) Solve(ctx context.Context, problem *pb.Problem) (*pb.Result, error) {

    /* Choose heuristic function */
    var heuristic npuzzle.Heuristic
    switch problem.Heuristic {
    case "hamming":
        heuristic = npuzzle.HammingDistance
    case "manhattan":
        heuristic = npuzzle.ManhattanDistance
    case "manhattan + linear conflicts":
        heuristic = npuzzle.ManhattanPlusLinearConflicts
    }

    /* Choose between greedy search and uniform-cost search */
    var goal npuzzle.Goal
    var search npuzzle.Search
    switch problem.Search {
    case "greedy":
        goal = npuzzle.GreedyGoalReached
        search = npuzzle.GreedySearch
    case "uniform-cost":
        goal = npuzzle.UniformCostGoalReached
        search = npuzzle.UniformCostSearch
    }

    /* Convert protobuf unsigned 32bits integer to regular integer */
    size := len(problem.Rows)
    m := make(npuzzle.Matrix, size)
    for y, row := range problem.Rows {
        m[y] = make([]int, size)
        for x, num := range row.Num {
            m[y][x] = int(num)
        }
    }

    log.Printf("received problem:\n - heuristic: %v\n - search: %v\n - matrix: %v\n", problem.Heuristic, problem.Search, m)
    if npuzzle.IsSolvable(m) == false {
        log.Println("failed to solve problem: unsolvable")
        return &pb.Result{
            Success: false,
            Error:   "unsolvable",
        }, nil
    }

    begin := time.Now()
    log.Printf("starting solve on %v...", m)
    res, totalNumberOfStates, maxNumberOfStates, err := m.Solve(heuristic, search, goal, 30*time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("timed ouf after %v", 30*time.Second)
        return &pb.Result{
            Success: false,
            Error:   fmt.Sprintf("timed ouf after %v", 30*time.Second),
        }, nil
    }

    duration := time.Since(begin)
    log.Printf("solved %v in %v seconds", m, duration)
    var path string
    if res.Parent == nil {
        path = "already solved!"
    } else {
        path = npuzzle.StringifyPath(res)
    }

    return &pb.Result{
        Success:     true,
        Time:        duration.String(),
        Moves:       int32(res.Cost),
        TotalStates: int32(totalNumberOfStates),
        MaxStates:   int32(maxNumberOfStates),
        Path:        path,
    }, nil
}

func main() {

    flag.Parse()
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("localhost:%d", *port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v\n", err)
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterNpuzzleServer(s, &server{})
    log.Printf("starting server on port %v\n", *port)
    log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v\n", s.Serve(lis))
}
```

I tried to launch the client and the server locally, and only containerize the envoy proxy, while trying different addresses (my docker machine IP address and localhost), but it didn't work. I also tried to launch all three containers but no result here either.
I'm unsure what to change to successfully manage to make my app work properly on MacOS.

Comment: Have you done integration tests? You sure your grpc works correctly?

Comment: Well it works perfectly on Linux, I only have this issue on mac.

Comment: I prolly would check the firewall. Other than that... *shrugs*